# Cosmological constant in General Relativity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, vacuum, cosmological-constant, ground-state

According to my GR notes the cosmological constant can be thought of as a vacuum energy much in the same way as the ground state of the harmonic oscillator. The notes claim that the regularised energy would then be expected to have a value of about the Planck mass to the power of 4. Can anyone shed some light on how he arrived at this value?